# When adding a new column to a table, should I create a new migration or edit an old one?

Tags: migration, ruby-on-rails-3

If I create a table with `rails generate migration`, I can add an extra column to it later by creating a new migration. I could also rollback the original migration and then edit it to include the extra column.

### Method 1: New Migration

```
//Create the model including the migration
$ rails generate model Foo bar:string

//Perform the migration
$ rake db:migrate

//Create the add column migration
$ rails generate migration add_foobar_to_foos foobar:string

//Perform the new migration
$ rake db:migrate
```

### Method 2: Rollback

```
//Create the model including the migration
$ rails generate model Foo bar:string

//Perform the migration
$ rake db:migrate

//Rollback the migration
$ rake db:rollback

//Edit the original migration file

//Perform the new migration
$ rake db:migrate
```

What is the correct/best way to accomplish this task and why?

Comment: Recommended way is to add the new column with a new migration.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ill go with method 1. why? because if other developers/machines are working with this environment you can get an inconstant state due to the fact that they might need to rollback at the right time in order to maintain correct db structure.

Comment: This is totally correct. If you alter an existing migration, other developers would need to pull it in and run those tricky bastard commands to get it to the same state as you, or even worse run `rake db:schema:load`. If you've committed a migration, it should *never* change.

Comment: I think I should have specified when it is ok to use rollback. if you created a migration but you haven't committed/pushed it, then it's ok to rollback and edit your migration.

Comment: I have a follow up question here... doesn't rake db:reset blow away the existing database and run all the migrations? If my project is in its infancy, and I want to amend a previous migration, couldn't I just edit the migration that creates the table, and then do a db:reset?

Comment: @jschank: Yes you can, but you will lose your data, so it is only suitable for certain scenarios. Using a new migration will work for most cases.